# "instance has no attribute" error, Python

Tags: python, button, attributeerror

I am writing a script on Python, which I want to run on Raspberry Pi.
I came into this curious case and I can't figure out what the problem is.

I just made a small edit, which  seems to run without any problems on my Laptop. I am using PyCharm IDE on Windows.
However, when I try to run the code on the Raspberry, it gives this error:

`"AttributeError: testProgram instance has no attribute 'measure_test_data'"`

```
class testProgram(TK.Toplevel):
def __init__(self):
    """Constructor"""
    TK.Toplevel.__init__(self)
    self.geometry("400x300")
    self.title("Test or Train")
    self.clf = ""

    self.testProgram = Button(self, text="Train from RAW data", command = self.train_data)
    self.testProgram.pack()

    self.testProgram = Button(self, text="Open trained data", command = self.open_exist_data)
    self.testProgram.pack()

    self.testProgram = Button(self, text="Test some data", command = self.test_data)
    self.testProgram.pack()

    self.testProgram = Button(self, text="Run a measurment and  test it", command = self.measure_test_data)
    self.testProgram.pack()
```

What I did is just adding another Button, the 4th one. I have also written a simple function for it:

```
   def measure_test_data(self):
       print("check?")
```

What I am missing? I am relatively new to Python, started a week ago and the thing I am missing may be something very obvious or simple..

Comment: This isn't your complete code. You probably have a indentation issue somewhere and the `measure_test_data` folds outside of the class. Could you post your entire class (and it's functions)?

Comment: Please proved the full code, and fix the indentation. We cant really help until we see the full code. It seems that `measure_test_data` is not present in that `class` to me.

Comment: for starters, your indentation is wrong, so this does not run at all.